# recursive code to non recursive with loops

Tags: java, combinations

Hello I want this code to non recursive how I can do it?

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{0, 1, 2,3};
        int size = 2;
        int[] tmp = new int[size];
        //Arrays.fill(tmp, -1);
        generateCombinations(array, 0, 0, tmp);
    }

    private static void generateCombinations(int[] array, int start, int depth, int[] tmp) {

        if (depth == tmp.length) {
            for (int j = 0; j < depth; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[tmp[j]]);

            } System.out.println();
            return;
        }
        for (int i = start; i < array.length; i++) {
            tmp[depth] = i;
            generateCombinations(array, i + 1, depth + 1, tmp);
        }

    }
}
```

It generates all the combinations from specific numbers.

Comment: What did *you* try so far? BTW: What programming language are we talking about? Please add it to the tags!

Comment: Why do you want it to be non-recursive? Recursion is one generic way to check for all combinations. If your case is very specific for `{0, 1, 2,3}` then there should be a way with three or four loops.

Comment: because is for a school assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every recursion could be rewritten to iteration and vice a versa. You just have to follow a common algorithm:

- [Replace Recursion with Iteration](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html)
- [Replace Iteration with Recursion](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceIterationWithRecursion.html)

> 1. Determine the base case of the Recursion. Base case, when reached, causes Recursion to end. Every Recursion must have a defined base
>      case. In addition, each recursive call must make a progress towards
>      the base case (otherwise recursive calls would be performed
>      infinitely). In our example the base case is n == 0.
> 2. Implement a loop that will iterate until the base case is reached.
> 3. Make a progress towards the base case. Send the new arguments to the top of the loop instead to the recursive method.

Behind this lies the concept of maintaining invariant condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Test {
    private final int[] array;
    private final int[] tmp;

    private Test(int[] array, int size) {
        tmp = new int[size];
        this.array = array;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test(new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3}, 2);
        t.generateCombinations();
    }

    /**
     * Print the selection.
     */
    private void print() {
        for (int i : tmp) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /**
     * Set values in tmp for indices startIndex, ..., (tmp.length-1)
     * to startValue, ..., (startValue-startIndex + tmp.length-1)
     * @param startIndex
     * @param startValue 
     */
    private void initMin(int startIndex, int startValue) {
        final int offset = startValue - startIndex;
        for (int i = startIndex; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            tmp[i] = i+offset;
        }
    }

    private void generateCombinations() {
        if (tmp.length == 0) return;
        initMin(0, 0);
        print();

        final int maxIndex = tmp.length-1;
        int index = maxIndex;
        final int z = array.length-tmp.length;

        while (index >= 0) {
            if (tmp[index] == index+z) {
                index--;
            } else {
                if (tmp[index]== index+z-1) {
                    // only value at index changes
                    tmp[index]++;
                    index--;
                } else {
                    initMin(index, tmp[index]+1);
                    index = maxIndex;
                }

                print();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The algorithm is based on the following observation:
`tmp[i]` must be at most `(i+array.length-tmp.length)`

The algorithm always always adds 1 at the last position, where this is still possible and sets the values at the following positions to the smallest possible values.